Build Android Darkmatter failed : bigdroid commant not found
I'm trying to compile Android DarkMatter from source following this guide :
https://wiki.aopc.dev/bigdroid/building-a-project/
This is what I did :
marietto@marietto-wayland-kde:~/Downloads$ curl --proto  
'=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSfL "https://git.io/Jc9bH" | bash -s 
selfinstall

[***] warn: Failed to retrieve a writable existing PATH    
directory
[%%%] info: Falling back to /home/marietto/.bashbox/bin
[%%%] info: Installing to /home/marietto/.bashbox/bin
[%%%] info: Restart your shell to update PATH env for   
bashbox
[%%%] info: Installation complete, run \bashbox --help` to 
get started`

marietto@marietto-wayland-kde:~/Downloads$ bashbox install   
bigdroid

marietto@marietto-wayland-kde:~/Downloads$ git clone   
https://github.com/supremegamers/darkmatter

Clone in 'darkmatter' in corso...
remote: Enumerating objects: 135, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (135/135), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (98/98), done.
remote: Total 135 (delta 43), reused 64 (delta 19), pack-  
reused 0 (from 0)
Ricezione degli oggetti: 100% (135/135), 18.63 KiB | 6.21   
MiB/s, fatto.
Risoluzione dei delta: 100% (43/43), fatto.

marietto@marietto-wayland-kde:~/Downloads$ cd darkmatter

marietto@marietto-wayland-kde:~/Downloads/darkmatter$  
bigdroid build --release

bigdroid: command not found

marietto@marietto-wayland-kde:~/Downloads/darkmatter$   
bigdroid build --release darkmatter

bigdroid: command not found`

I've searched the executable bigdroid everywhere on the disk,but I didn't find it....
That it starts to compile and/or that it finds the executable called "bigdroid".
